# Cron job results are different from executing from own shell

Tags: shell, cron

I am using Ubuntu 12.0.4
I have a script basically with the following codes:

```
lockfile=/var/tmp/mylock

if ( set -o noclobber; echo "$$" > "$lockfile") 2> /dev/null; then
    exit_normally "instance is running"
else
    echo "no instance is running"
fi
```

The file /var/tmp/mylock doesn't exists in my system, so when I execute my script manually I get "no instance is running" which is correct.

But when the shell script is executed by cron, it always return "instance is running"

I am not sure where to check or what to look for to find the root cause for the problem above, hopefuly I can get a few pointers here..

Comment: Not sure the answer, but it'll boil down to environmental. As a general point on problems like these, you might try to break it apart into separate pieces in the same temporary/test/one-time script, echo plenty of return codes and don't suppress any errors. For example, take the subshell commands, execute each individually then `echo $?` after each and then once again altogether as a subshell and `echo $?` that as well. Something will jump out at you. You can schedule that as a one time cronjob and examine the email generated.

Comment: Is it the same shell in both cases? Try this: `( set -o noclobber; echo $? > "$ecfile"; shopt > "$debugfile"; echo "$SHELL";)`

Comment: Just explicitly force a shell through a shebang line ( #!/bin/bash ) or by using `bash /your/path/and/file`)

Comment: Post the full script. Also, add `set -x` at the top of the script just below the `#!` line, run the script from the command line, run the script from cron, and post both resulting traces.

Answer (score 3):

As a general practice, creating a file and expecting the OS to not clobber it if it exists isn't a good way to test if it exists.

You'd be better served with:

```
if [ -f $lockfile ]; then
  exit_normally "instance is running"
else
  echo "no instance is running"
fi
```

However, if you're trying to use the existence of a file as a lockfile, you'd probably be better off using the unix lockfile command:

```
lockfile -r 0 $lockfile
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  exit_normally "instance is running"
else
  echo "no instance is running"
fi
```